# Get details of Fingerprint sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors, fingerprint

I want to get the fingerprint sensor's details. I know that you could do something like the following to get the details of the light sensor:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

if (sensorManager != null)
    Sensor lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

String name = lightSensor.getName();
String vendor = lightSensor.getVendor();
int version = lightSensor.getVersion();
float power = lightSensor.getPower();
float resolution = lightSensor.getResolution();
float maxRange = lightSensor.getMaximumRange();
```

I can't find a way to get the details of the fingerprint sensor. Is it even possible? If not, why?

Comment: What **specifically** do you mean by "details of the fingerprint sensor"?

Comment: @CommonsWare By "details" I mean some hardware specifications which may help if the fingerprint sensor is malfunctioning and the user has to replace it.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing like that in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw fingerprint data or derivatives (for example, templates) must never be accessible from outside the sensor driver or TEE. If the hardware supports a TEE, hardware access must be limited to the TEE and protected by an SELinux policy.

Source : https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal